# Django QuerySet Filtering – Intersect Clause in Field Lookups?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following models, where Questions and Choices have a many-to-many relationship. (To understand it better, consider a poll where each Question can have multiple Choices and each Choice can be associated to multiple Questions.)

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField('Choice')

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now suppose I have a QuerySet consisting of Choice objects, call it `universe_choices`. I want to filter all Question objects, to get only those Questions whose choices have at least one element in common with `universe_choices`. In other words, if at least one of a Question's `choices` is also in `universe_choices`, include that Question in the QuerySet returned from my filter.

Ideally, I would do this with something equivalent to:

```py
Question.objects.filter(choices__intersection__exists=universe_choices)
```

or

```py
Question.objects.filter(choices.intersection(universe_choices).exists())
```

But obviously neither the `intersection()` nor `exists()` methods exist in lookup-form, and you can't use them as-is in a filtering query.

**Is there a way to do this?**

The inefficient work-around of course is to loop through all Question objects, and check whether there is an intersection between each iteration's `Question.choices` object and `universe_choices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it very simply with this:

```
Question.objects.filter(choices__in=universe_choices)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in (The documentation doesn't seem to describe or give examples of doing it when the thing on the left hand side of the `__in` is multi-valued, but I've definitely used it for an identical use case and had it work as desired.)

Comment: Thanks for reading my mind :) I was unsure whether `__in` would handle a multi-value list as "any one of these is in" as opposed to "all of these must be in", but the fact that you've tried it helps.